# How to select 1 Gridviews in a event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have 2 gridviews which update some data, they are independent each one,
both are using "onrowupdating="actualizar" 
i want to use the same event like below:

> protected void actualizar(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs
>   e)
>           { }

How can  i select the specific grid view inside the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `object sender` will be the GridView who started the event so you can cast it to GridView and you will have it's properties like its Id.

Example:
`(sender as GridView).ID`

Answer (score 0):

Thats the answer !!

```
 Control cntrl = sender as GridView;
  var gridId = cntrl.ID;
```